# html2canvas in production

Tags: html2canvas, production

I saw your statement:
The script is still in a very experimental state, so I don't recommend using it in a production environment nor start building applications with it yet, as there will be still major changes made.

Does this still hold true or can we use it in production as it seems to do the job of taking screenshots of our chartjs charts and html tables.
We did see svg is not being rendered in the pdf but that may be the issue with jsPDF latest version which I believe is fixed but waiting to be released.

thanks
Az